# Linux : How can i find compilation flag of library provided by Opensuse i.e libOSmesa.so?

Tags: linux, compilation, opensuse

I want to know compilation flag used to compile library provided by OpenSUSE.
i.e libOSmesa.so provided by OpenSUSE. Is there any way to find out  flags used in compiling these libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check build logs in OBS, see "Build Results" widget on package page. For example [Mesa package](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE:13.2/Mesa) in openSUSE 13.2: https://build.opensuse.org/build/openSUSE:13.2/standard/x86_64/Mesa/_log
If you are looking for default C/C++ build flags, use `rpm --eval "%{optflags}"`

Comment: Yes . it is what i want . Thanks